# Use sed to retrieve variable from 1 file and place it in another

Tags: files, sed, variable

I need to use sed to retrieve a variable form within a file name. I am updating a previous code:

```
cat /directory/filename1.xml | sed -e "s/XYZABC/${c}/g" > /directory/filename2.xml
```

The value for `${c}` is in another file and it will change each day. How do I do this with sed?

Here is some additional context. I apologize for failing to include it originally. `${c}` is a sqlplus variable used to store the count of a query. I need to retrieve that count from a file. It is saved in the file as `Count=[$c]` where `[$c]` becomes the count from the query. I need to have `$c` replace XYZABC from the first xml file and save the results into a new xml file.

---

UPDATE: In case anyone has a similar issue I got mine to work using:

```
rm /directory/folder/variablefilename.dat
echo $c >> /directory/folder/variablefilename.dat

d=$(grep [0-9] /directory/folder/variablefilename.dat)

sed -3 "s/ABC123/${d}/g" /directory/folder/inputfile.xml >> /directory/folder/outputfile.xml
```

Comment: the whole file is `$c`? or only a part? if the latter, what are the criteria for determining what is `$c` and what isn't?

Comment: please edit any relevant information into the question. consider providing code-block formatted i/o examples - they are generally the most effective means of conveying your purpose.

Answer (score 1):

Normally if you want to use sed (or perl, or ruby) to modify a file, you add the `-i` option. Let's say we're talking an attribute assignment in XML:

```
changeit() {
  let newval="$1"
  shift; 
  # "$@" now contains all filenames
  sed -i -e 's/(XYZABC[[:space:]]*=[[:space:]]*)"([^"]*)"/\1"'"$newval"'";/' "$@"
}

changeit happy-happy /directory/filename1.xml
```

Before you test, please make a backup copy of the directory/files and do diffs afterwards. `sed -i` can be very destructive.

Note, this applies the substituion once per line. See other questions / answers for once per file. For multiple times per line, add `g` after the last slash (`/`).

An explanation of the quoting rules: I'm assuming well-formed XML encapsulates attribute values in double-quotes. So we're looking for `VARNAME = "something"`. This works as long as *something* doesn't itself contain an escaped double-quote character. So we have to keep the double-quotes from the shell, and for that we using single-quotes. In doing so, we prevent the variable `$newval` from being interpolated. So we have to close off the quoted part of the command, just before the variable expansion, then expand `$newval`, which should now be double-quoted to prevent shell from thinking embedded spaces start a new argument (and therefore filename) to sed, and then resume single-quoting so we can replace the double-quotes as part of sed's output.

Comment: ... and I just read comments to your question. *facepalm*